# Updating value in the child component , on value changes in the parent component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am working in Angular ,where -

- I am trying to Update value in the child component , on value changes
  in the parent component

  **(as value is coming dynamically to the parent component from some other component)** .

**How I tried**

- I tried to pass data from parent component to child component Using
  @Input decorator
- using @Input value is passed just  once when component loads  and
  latter on value is not passed

I am sharing my code below

**Parent component**

.html

```
<app-banner [tournamentType]='tournamentType'></app-banner>
```

.ts

**child component**

.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit , Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicesService } from '../service/services.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.scss']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tournamentType;

  sportsType : any = 1;



  constructor(private rest : ServicesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("this. is banner page" + this.tournamentType);
    alert('hello');

    this.loadDataFromApi(1);
  }

  loadDataFromApi(sportsType) {

     this.rest.getbanner(this.sportsType).then(res => {
       console.log('>>>$$$$$ banner >>>>>> $$$$$$$$$$');
       console.log('  @Input tournamentType; ====' + this.tournamentType );
       console.log(res);

     })
    console.log(sportsType);
  }
}
```

Comment: is `tournamentType` an object or array?

Comment: share us your parent.componen.ts code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Values changes from parent to child components are reflected immediately. However, you can listen for value changes event in the child component. Read more about [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)

Here is an example on [stackblitz](https://angular-tu3vru.stackblitz.io)

**app.component.html**

```html
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<app-child [data]="count"></app-child>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";

  count = 0;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => this.updateCount(), 1000);
  }

  updateCount(): void {
    this.count++;
  }
}
```

**child.component.html**

```html
<p>{{data}}</p>
```

**child.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-child",
  templateUrl: "./child.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./child.component.css"],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() data: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log("value changed", this.data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Say this is your parent component.

```js
    import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';        

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{

        message = "hello again";
        friends:string[] = [];

        //will add friend to our list of friends array
        add(friend){
            if(friend.value){
                this.friends.push(friend.value);    
                friend.value = "";
            }
            console.log(this.friends);
        }

        ngAfterViewInit() {    
            
        }

    }
```

Parent Component UI

```html
    <div>
        <input #friend type="text" placeholder="name of friend" />
        <button type="button" (click)="add(friend)">add friend</button>
    </div>

    <app-to-child message="List of friends" [friends]="friends"></app-to-child>
```

Now child component

Use @Input decorator with fields in which you want to receive data from the parent component.

```js
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-to-child',
        templateUrl: './to-child.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./to-child.component.css']
    })
    export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() message:string;
      @Input() friends:string[];
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      //this will called when data is passed from parent to child.
      ngOnChanges(val){
          console.log("change detected");
          console.log(val);                
      }

   }
```

inside child.component.html

```html
      <h5>CHILD COMPONENT</h5>
      <p>Message : {{message}}</p>
      <div *ngFor="let friend of friends"> {{friend}}</div>
```

You can learn more about `component interactions` [here](https://github.com/nitin7dc/angular-component-interaction), a quick walk through.

Comment: implement OnChanges